# Ho do I convert an "EagleCAD 5.12" project to "KiCad 5.0.2"?

Tags: eaglecad, kicad

I have an existing project in Eagle 5.12.  I'd like to convert it to KiCad 5.0.2 (this is the latest I downloaded today).

I have tried using the KiCad File/Import Project.  It failed.  I suspect it wants Eagle 6.0 or later, but I have found no concrete list of what Eagle versions are supported.

I found an Eagle ULP named eagle2kicad.ulp designed for Eagle 5.8.  I tried running that, but it only did the schematic, and failed with many errors.  The resulting schematic was completely unusable.  I suspect this ULP was written for an earlier version of KiCad.

What do I need to do to convert a Eagle 5.12 project (both board and schematic, including all library symbols, etc...) to KiCad 5.0.2?

Comment: Is it too big to open and save in a newer Eagle?

Comment: I have an eagle 6 license, I can re-save it for you if you can't find another option.

Answer (score 2):

The KiCad Eagle importer is based off of the [Eagle 7 DTD](http://makerstorage.com/eagledtd/) but should also work with Eagle 6 files.  Your file may need to be converted before it can be imported.  You could try this using the Eagle 7 program (Open in Eagle, re-save then import)

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, it was Version 5.91 from 2011, where EAGLE changed from a proprietary, binary file format to an XML format to store project files.

I guess KiCAD can read the XML format only, and so supports only files created with 5.91 or later.

If your project uses features from a licensed (paid) EAGLE version, you can open it with the most recent free version, but not save it. But if you update to the latest v5 release, it should work.